# Unity android game gives App not installed on phones and blustacks

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I created 2D game on unity and build it. But it can't be installed on phones. Here is my build settings.

[other settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE53Q.png)

[other settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEJAH.png)

[other settings 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z99SU.png)

I tried change build settings and my android device. It didn't worked. I am expecting to someone help me about that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What happened when you tried to install it on a phone? Did you get an error? If so then please edit the full error message into your question.

Comment: No ı did not get any errors, it just said "App not installed". I tried it on bluestacks too.